# VBs to query AD

Tags: active-directory, vbscript

I'm trying to get authentication with AD and to do this I've already made this code. Can anyone provide me if it's correct or not to do this or if I have a better solution.

```
On Error Resume Next

Set obj = GetObject("ldap://serverip/DC=xx, DC=xx")
WScript.Echo "A: " & obj.name

WScript.Echo "init script"

strUser = "TESTAD\Administrador"
strPass = "test"
strDC = "serverip" ' this has to be FQDN of the DC
strAccount = "Administrador" 'Use the sAMAccountname (logon name)  value here instead of CN

Const ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = 0
Const ADS_SERVER_BIND = 389

Set objDSO = GetObject("LDAP:")
Set objRootDse = objDSO.OpenDSObject("LDAP://" & strDC & "/RootDSE", strUser, strPass, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION OR ADS_SERVER_BIND)
strTargetDncDomain = objRootDse.Get("defaultNamingContext")

strBase    = "<LDAP://" & strDC & "/" & strTargetDncDomain & ">;"

strAttrs = "cn=administrador,cn=Users,dc=xx, dc=xx"
strScope = "subtree"
strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountname=" & strAccount & "));"

strQuery = strBase & strFilter & strAttrs & strScope

Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
oConnection.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
oConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider", strUser, strPass

Set oCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
oCommand.ActiveConnection = oConnection
oCommand.CommandTimeout = 30

oCommand.CommandText = strQuery

Set objRS = oCommand.Execute
Do While Not objRS.EOF
   strDnFound = objRS.Fields("CN")
    wscript.echo "found it!"
    wscript.echo "query: " & strQuery
    wscript.echo strTargetDncDomain
   wscript.echo strDnFound ' Just so that we know it's working
   objRS.MoveNext
Loop 

objRS.close
oConnection.close
```

It's they first time doing this so i was looking for some help. And also after this I want to save the results into a txt file, it's correct to use

```
cscript.exe //NoLogo "C:\path\to\your.vbs" >"C:\output.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i finish with this transforming this "search" into a actual authorization login

```
for i = 1 to 100000
    Set xResult = GetObject("LDAP:").OpenDSObject("LDAP://serverip", "username", "password", ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION + ADS_SERVER_BIND)
    wscript.echo now & ": ejec: " & i  &  " - dummy data: " & xResult.Class
next
```